# Firebase ID Token change when password reset

Tags: firebase, cookies, firebase-authentication

I use Firebase ID Tokens to show data on my site when someone is logging in.
I save the token in a cookie on the client side and when the client accesses the website it takes the token from his cookie file and sends it to my backend server.

I would like to remove all ID Tokens when a password is reset so all the logged in clients using that username and password would disconnect.

Is this option valid? If so how can you do it? They don't seem to mention it in their docs.

Comment: Is it really necessary to store the ID token in a cookie at all?  After a user is logged in to Firebase, you can always retrieve their ID token using firebase.auth.currentUser.getIdToken().  You can also manage how the Firebase authentication state is persisted when the user leaves your site (see https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/auth-state-persistence).  You haven't explained your entire use case, but those two items might let you achieve what you want without using any cookies.

Comment: This is how my current system works: I have firebase functions that listen for GET requests from my website for login input. After they get the email and password using the GET request they log in the user from the backend and send the user only the important things I chose to display. I don't login to firebase from client side, the login occurs server side and sent to the client. This is how I can use PHP to send the token to my backend check it and send data

Comment: I am a little confused.  Does the user enter their ID/password on your web client, which then passes the ID/password to your PHP backend, then your PHP backend sends the ID/password to a Firebase function?  Where does the actual Firebase authentication happen - in PHP code or in a Firebase function?  Or do I completely misunderstand your setup?

Comment: The authentication happens in the firebase function via a GET request. After that I use some PHP and another GET request to get the users data from the function.

Answer (score 1):

When a user's password is reset, changed or the associated email is updated, Firebase Auth will invalidate all existing sessions for that user for security reasons. This effectively invalidates that user's ID token from the perspective of Firebase Auth backend. The refresh token will also not be able to issue a new ID token.

Also I agree with Scott. You should use `currentUser.getIdToken()` to get the ID token instead of storing it yourself. This API takes care of refreshing the ID token for you when it expires.

Comment: Perhaps I didn't explain my intention well enough, please take a look at what I replied to Scott.

Comment: I assume, you pass the email/pass to an Cloud Function endpoint where you sign in and return the ID token to the client. In that case, the same is still true: the ID token will be invalidated from the Auth backend's perspective, but it may not be possible to easily detect that on your end without adding your own handler for the password reset to notify your backend about the invalidation. Learn more on how to build your own landing page for password reset: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/custom-email-handler

Comment: The thing is, ID tokens have a short lifespan and I don't know if I can delete a token.

Comment: When you say you want to "remove all ID Tokens" and "delete a token", do you mean make them invalid to Firebase?  If so, then this is the correct answer - Firebase will do that itself whenever a password is reset.

Comment: I tried that, it doesn't make them invalid. I don't think I will use their ID tokens because they don't last very long too, as well as not update, unfortunately. That means I will need to create my own and store them on my own if I am right.

Comment: Trust me, they are invalidated from the Auth backend. The Auth backend will invalidate them but if you use the Admin SDK to `verifyIdToken`, they will be considered valid (since no RPC is made to the Auth backend) until the end of their natural lifetime (one hour). You could keep track of the invalidation time and check the `auth_time` in the token to enforce that it is greater than the invalidation time. The Firebase Auth team is looking into simplifying that for developers.

Comment: Maybe I can change the exp value of the token by myself? So I can make them last as long as I want and delete them when I want?

Comment: You can't change the expiration time of the ID token. It is fixed by the Firebase Auth backend.